# Как заполнить NaN если возможно одно значение?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Представим таблицу из двух колонок в датафрейме:

```
0 NaN
0 NaN 
0 1
1 0
1 5
1 NaN
2 0
0 NaN
0 1
2 1
2 NaN
3 NaN
3 500
3 NaN
```

Как быстро заполнить справа `NaN` только напротив тех значений слева, для которых существует, важный момент, как `NaN` так и только единственное не `NaN` значение справа?

Желаемый результат:

```
0 1
0 1
0 1
1 0
1 5
1 NaN
2 0
0 1
0 1
2 1
2 NaN
3 500
3 500
3 500
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а что значит "для которых существует как nan так и только единственное значение справа (не nan)"?

Comment: а ниже коллега решил, но хочется не циклом, а map'ом как-нибудь - это будет быстрее, а то массив около млн записей с 500 колонками.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [251]: tmp = df.groupby("grp")["val"].agg(["first", "nunique"]).query("nunique == 1")["first"]

In [252]: df.loc[df["val"].isna(), "val"] = df["grp"].map(tmp).dropna()

In [253]: df
Out[253]:
    grp    val
0     0    1.0
1     0    1.0
2     0    1.0
3     1    0.0
4     1    5.0
5     1    NaN
6     2    0.0
7     0    1.0
8     0    1.0
9     2    1.0
10    2    NaN
11    3  500.0
12    3  500.0
13    3  500.0
```

Comment: Тоже неплохо! Спасибо, Максим.

Comment: скоро приведу сравнение по скорости обработки имеющиеся алгоритмы

Comment: @AlexandrKosolapov, и как там сравнение по скорости? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял условие, то можно сделать так:

исходный df:

```
    left  right
0      0    NaN
1      0    NaN
2      0    1.0
3      1    0.0
4      1    5.0
5      1    NaN
6      2    0.0
7      0    NaN
8      0    1.0
9      2    1.0
10     2    NaN
```

Далее:

```
df1 = df.groupby('left')
for k, v in df1:
    if df1.get_group(k).nunique()['right'] <= 1:
        df.loc[df['left']==k] = 1
```

получаем в df:

```
    left  right
0      1    1.0
1      1    1.0
2      1    1.0
3      1    0.0
4      1    5.0
5      1    NaN
6      2    0.0
7      1    1.0
8      1    1.0
9      2    1.0
10     2    NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли использовать каким-то образом map, и для ситуаций когда у нас могут быть не только единицы)

Comment: Если у вас могут быть не только единицы где?

Comment: добавил в пример выше)